# In a flutter project, I have two list based on two different class with one simillar property, I want to show output based on 'id' from both classes

Tags: flutter, dart

In a flutter project, I have two lists based on two different class with one similar property, I want to show output based on 'id' from both classes.

I want to show the data content in a GridView.builder() based on 'id', When I tap 'Dhaka' it will show only Dhaka based Data, the same expectation for 'Chittagong'

this is `DivisionClass`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class DivisionClass {
  final String? id;
  final String? divisionName;
  final String? divisionDescription;
  final String? dImageUrl;

  DivisionClass({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.divisionName,
    @required this.divisionDescription,
    @required this.dImageUrl,
  });
}

class DivisionLists with ChangeNotifier {
   final List<DivisionClass> _divisionList = [
    DivisionClass(
        id: 'Chittagong',
        divisionName: 'Chittagong',
        dImageUrl:
            'https://tbbd-flight.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/blog_e4v9wwcJyMp7IsKETHh15wqtY4eohvv.jpg',
        divisionDescription: 'The city of magical words and natural views!'),
    DivisionClass(
        id: 'Dhaka',
        divisionName: 'Dhaka',
        dImageUrl:
            'https://cdn.britannica.com/97/189797-050-1FC0041B/Night-view-Dhaka-Bangladesh.jpg',
        divisionDescription: 'The artificial city with pure exploring'),
  ];
  List<DivisionClass> get divisionList{
    return _divisionList;
  }
}
```

//this is Locations Class

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Locations {
  final String? id;
  final String? locationName;
  final String? locationDescription;
  final String? dImageUrl;

  Locations({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.locationName,
    @required this.locationDescription,
    @required this.dImageUrl,
  });
}

class LocationLists with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Locations> _locationlists = [
    Locations(
        id: 'Chittagong',
        locationName: 'Cox\'s Bazar',
        locationDescription: 'The Longest sea beach in the world',
        dImageUrl:
            'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/15/99/54/30/swimming-pool.jpg'),
    Locations(
        id: 'Chittagong',
        locationName: 'Bandarban',
        locationDescription: 'The heaven of green!',
        dImageUrl:
            'https://cosmosgroup.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/news/y8eC0WBzPEEVyKIGGjcM3zKIgirEYLTLvioF3GaP.jpeg'),
    Locations(
        id: 'Dhaka',
        locationName: 'University of Dhaka',
        locationDescription: 'The Oxford of of Bangladesh',
        dImageUrl:
            'https://allbanglanewspaper.net/upload/2019/03/f214a1-dhaka-university.jpg'),
    Locations(
        id: 'Dhaka',
        locationName: 'Jahangirnagar University',
        locationDescription: 'The Largest Campus',
        dImageUrl:
            'https://images.thedailystar.net/sites/default/files/images/2022/01/06/ju_main_gate.jpg'),
  ];

  List<Locations> get locationList {
    return _locationlists;
  }
```

Comment: can you include your widget class that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`firstWhere`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) method to in conjunction with `GridView.builder` to get the elements by their ID.

For example:

```dart
GridView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final id = locationLists.locationList[index].id;
        final locationItem = locationLists.locationList[index];
        final divisionItem = divisionLists.divisionList
            .firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);
        // Continue the logic here
      },
    )
```